# CentOS packages vs NextCloud

Tags: server, nextcloud

I have intention to reuse one of my Pi3 into a home server for multiples services (yet to be decided). I am new to servers and hence using the Pi for exploration and monkeying around.

If I understand things correctly, NextCloud is a consolidation, offers GUI to key possible functionality one would like to have in a home(non-home) server. The same could be achieved with packages in CentOS, CentOS being a server-type OS. My question is if there would be a large performance hit using NextCloud instead of yum packages. As Rpi3 is amongst the low-end range hardware for home servers, I am concerned about performance.

Please feel free to correct my understanding if I got things wrong.